# Showing the output of a shell script on the browser

Tags: java, ajax, shell

This is my first question here,so pardon if somewhere i go wrong.
i am trying to call a shell script on the server from the html page using Ajax.
The Ajax function is calling the java action and this java action class is invoking a shell script.
The shell script will be writing the outputs as it runs.
I want to show that output on the browser in the same way it appears on the shell.

the way i am doing it now is writing the output of the shell in a file and then show up the content of that file on the web page,but all i want is to show the outputs on the webpage as soon as the scripts writes it .
The script takes 2 minutes to run and while running ,it keeps on writing the outputs on the shell.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to `start()` the shell script via the [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) class.

Once you have the [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) instance, you can obtain its standard output and standard error streams via [getOutputStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getOutputStream%28%29) and [getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#getErrorStream%28%29) respectively.

These InputStreams contain the output you are looking for. As you read them you can then write their output to your servlet or JSP's response output stream.  You'll need to do something like [waitFor()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor%28%29) the process and create thread(s) to read its output and write to your servlet's response.

Comment: Thanks for the reply ,I will work that out and will update you with the same.

Comment: i am able to redirect the stream of my shell script to my html response using printwriter,
But as long as the stream is unfinished ,my page gets stuck(Until full response comes from the server)
So if in a script i print one line say echo "i am sleeping"
and then i sleep for 5 mins.
.I want to print "i am sleeping " on the web page as soon as it is written.and then wait for next output .As shell stream is writing in the response stream,is there any way i can get the data which is in the response stream,before stream gets flushed or closed?